# How do I get VM Guests connected to VLANs trunked to the host server, but keep the host server inaccessible?

Tags: networking, virtualization, vlan

I'm experimenting with separating my home network to various VLANs (mainly for security and routing purposes) and I need to connect various virtual machines to their respective VLANs (VoIP, IP Cams, Wlan for guests etc). I prefer KVM but it's not a must.

I have one VM host server connected by one UTP cable to the switch, with all necessary VLANs assigned to the port. The host server has the VLAN interfaces configured and working (eth0 for the untagged traffic, eth0.1, eth0.2 ... for the tagged VLAN traffic).

**What I want to achieve is that the hosts can connect to their VLANs (guest0 to eth0.0, guest1 to eth0.1 and so on), but the host server doesn't have an assigned IP address in those VLANs.** My aim is to hide the existence of the host server from all those bitcoin mining virus infested ddosing gadgets that may be present on those VLANs.

I'm quite new to all this so perhaps I'm missing a simple basic thing, but I just can't seem to get my google search wording right for this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer this from a VMware view point.  Probably can be done on KVM as well, I'm just not sure.  What you want to do is create different port groups on your vSwitch.  Each port group has its own VLAN id (same as 802.11q VLAN tagging, use VLAN ID 4095 for all untagged traffic).  You put the Vmkernel port in its own VLAN on its own port group, and then you have separation at the network layer.

If you want to allow some access, then setup a router between those two VLANs and set firewall rules to allow/block certain traffic.  But without the router, you are effectively segmenting the traffic to different VLANs.